# HTML table behavior changed by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour on a Magento webshop of a client. We've created an attribute that holds information about the product. This (technical) information is contained in an html table and is displayed on a tab powered by an "Easytabs" extension". Everything works as expected except for the tables that we use. For some strange reason the following example code:

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Is changed to:

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I also noticed that in my list styles returns are added. A normal list style layout would look as follows in a browser:

```html
   <ul>
   <br>
    <li>Test 1</li>
   <br>
   <li>Test 2</li>
   <br>
  </ul>
```

What could cause this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Magento transforms new lines into `<br>` automatically.

I recommend you to read this, explains the issue very well:
http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2012/08/removing-automatic-line-breaks-from-magentos-product-descriptions/

Comment: Indeed an interesting article, I'll have a look at it!